# What battery do I need for a 35mm film Canon Rebel?

Tags: canon, film, battery

I have a Canon EOS Rebel 35mm film camera for my photography class and I need a battery, it didn't come with one. What battery do I need to buy?

Answer (score 9):

*(from comments)*

Find the exact model here, and look for the specifications: http://www.canon.com/camera-museum/camera/film/series_eos.html

Note that there are many different models that are called "Canon EOS Rebel something", and some of them use different kinds of batteries. For example, EOS Rebel XS seems to use CR123A batteries while EOS Rebel 2000 uses CR2 batteries (both of these models are 35mm film cameras).

Answer (score 1):

My Canon EOS Rebel G, about 15-20 years old, takes two CR123A batteries

Answer (score 0):

Canon EOS Rebel 35mm takes 2CR5 battery type.

Comment: Almost 2 years after the question was asked, I suspect that they've found the batteries they need...

Comment: JoanneC: yes, but at this point the battery may be almost dead so they might need another. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have two Canon Rebel bodies with no other identification. I will find the 2CR5 battery and see if it will fit.